# Issue on Drawing Highcharts From Selected Row Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can you please take a look at this code  and let me know why I am not load data into the highcharts series data like : `checkedRows[0][2]` in

```
 data: [checkedRows[0][2], 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
```

Here is the js code which I have:

```
$(function () {
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var checkCounter = 0;
        var checkedRows = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {

            checkedRows.push(
              $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                  return $(this).html();
              }).get()
            ); 
         });

  $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -80
        },

        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [checkedRows[0][2], 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual Spending',
            data: [checkedRows[1][2], 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]

    });   
   });
```

I also alert the  `checkedRows[0][1]` which is returning correctly but it is not working in highchart data array

Here the Html

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
             <td>Model 1</td>
            <td>43000</td>
            <td>19000</td>
            <td>63000</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>60000</td>
            <td>12000</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>Model 2</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>50000</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>88000</td>
            <td>44000</td>
            <td>30000</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table><br />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array contains the text value of the table element, not a numeric value. You can convert like this:

```
parseInt(checkedRows[0][1])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/st99zoxm/